# ControlP5 Textarea space character issue

Tags: java, text, nullpointerexception, processing

I've encountered this issue with ControlP5 when using the TextArea object:

When calling '`setText(fooString)`' if fooString contains a ' ' in a line by itself, Java will throw a null pointer exception.

For example:

```
void setup()
{
  size(300,300);
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  textArea = cp5.addTextarea("txt")
                  .setPosition(0,0)
                  .setSize(30,30)
                  .setFont(createFont("arial",12))
                  .setLineHeight(14)
                  .setColor(color(0))
                  .setColorBackground(color(0))
                  .setColorForeground(color(255,100));
                  ;
  String s = "Hello\n       \nworld";
  textArea.setText(s);
}
```

Java throws: "`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`" and "`NullPointerException`"

My workaround (ignoring the case that s = "[a bunch of spaces]"):

```
s = s.replaceAll("\r", "\n");    // Use just one type of new line
s = s.replaceAll("\n +", "\n");  // Case 1
s = s.replaceAll(" +\n", "\n");  // Case 2
```

Is there a better way to fixing this or is a bug (on my part) with the above code?

Comment: What version of ControlP5 are you using ? I've just tested this: `import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;
Textarea textArea;
void setup()
{
  size(300,300);
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  textArea = cp5.addTextarea("txt","txt",0,0,30,60);
  String s = "Hello\n       \nworld";
  textArea.setText(s);
}` with 0.5.4 and it works fine

Comment: Hmm, according to the library.properties file: 2.0.4, which appears to be the [latest version](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/#installation).